# google map api v2 android - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

i am new to android programming. i am working on a project in which i have to get maps from google map. The eclipse is not found a warning or error code. i don't know what's went wrong into my code. please help me

```
    06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kulinerku/com.kulinerku.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at com.kulinerku.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
06-07 09:39:29.357: E/AndroidRuntime(432):  ... 11 more
```

my MainActivity.java

```
package com.kulinerku;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    final int RQS_GooglePlayService = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

        LatLng jogja = new LatLng(-7.782939, 110.367050);
        MarkerOptions markerJogja = new MarkerOptions();
        markerJogja.position(jogja);
        markerJogja.title("Tugu Jogja");
        markerJogja.snippet("Tugu Jogja adalah landmark Kota Jogja");

        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
        myMap.addMarker(markerJogja);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(jogja, 15));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kulinerku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.kulinerjogja.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>



    <uses-permission android:name="com.kulinerku.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature 
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAEUM5FPpkLC0kPGMOnmyTSEwEcRNLjo7s"/>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.kulinerku.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:name="com.kulinerku.MainActivity"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: I bet your `myMap` object is null

Answer (score 0):

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists. This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view; however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

from http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

Make sure you follow all the steps for using Google Play services (including importing the project, etc) here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html